# Pagination error invalid token for Rest API Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, rest, azure-rest-api

I am trying to use rest api to do pagination as it is just sending the first page in Azure ADF going to blob storage. I am currently using AbsoluteUrl and $['@odata.nextLink'] to get over all the pages, the issue is I am getting this error, I have used first used the token activity to get the token and then used it in copy activity where the source is rest api dataset with headers dynamically coming from token activity and then used pagination. Can you point me in the right direction on if this is the correct approach or am I missing something.

[image]

This is how the import schema looks like:

[image]

And the error after importing schema

[image]

This is how my rest api configuration look like:

[image]

And this is how my token all web activity looks like:

[image]

Edit 2:

This is how the output is for Web activity:

[image]

Including the part of the snip that missed the access token:

[image]

This is the output for Copy Activity when Pagination is on:

[image]

This is the setup of the pipeline:

[image]

Comment: yea you have the right approach, are you correctly using the access_token in the additional authorization header in CopyData activity source ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT Yes I am using access_token in additional authorization header in Copy activity. Key: Authorization and Value: Bearer @{activity('Web').output.access_token}

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I am doing everything right, but still I am getting this error where for the next page it is still throwing this error "Invalid Token". I manually used the pagination next page url and concatenated the "&access_token=VVAihQP3Hg2atCSn" to the link and it show the page. I am wondering if it is possible to do it in pagination AbsoluteUrl using dynamic function?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT When I try to import schema, I am getting the error invalid access token even when the token is active and referenced correctly.

Comment: did you try concatenating for authorization header `@concat('Bearer', activity('Login').output.access_token)`

Answer (score 0):

HttpStatusCode 401 indicates the authentication was not completed or failed due to invalid credentials. It maybe that the access token is missing in request from copy activity or not referenced properly or is expired. Make sure you already have the right access to this API.

Here is an example with basic configuration requirements:

1. Get the access token

[image]

[image]

2. Ensure you are able to reference it dynamically using *Add dynamic content* fields. Modify the reference with respect to the output you have received from earlier *Login Activity*.

   - Additional headers: `Authorization: @concat('Bearer', activity('Login').output.access_token)`
   - AbsoluteUrl: `${result_root}.{nextPageURL}`

Here is the official doc on [Pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) refer the supported Key and value pairs.

If you are getting the access token correctly but still seeing the error, try to **Import Schema** in *Mapping Settings* of copy activity. And make sure the `nextPageUrl` or `odata.nextLink` in your case is mapped correctly.

[image]

Recheck  **$['@odata.nextLink']** , AbsoluteUrl value as:

`$.rootElementName.CollectionOfItems.nextLinkURL`

Comment: To get the access token in the web activity, I used post method and I have used Contect-Type as the token url not application/json, is that correct? The rest is as you have mentioned. When I try to get the mapping import schema it gives invalid token error.

Comment: I am using this one @concat('Bearer ', activity('Token').output.access_token) and it works. When I try to import schema it throws invalid token error.

Comment: Great! it works. But technically import schema would just fetch the output from your previous web activity no matter what value you provide for parameters or additional headers given it was run successfully. Can you try publish all and preview data for source in copy activity

Comment: My apologies, it works in the sense, I am not having issue with Additional headers, like Authorization and @concat('Bearer ', activity('Token').output.access_token) except when I try to use pagination rule, it still throws error as invalid token. The same thing happens when I try import schema. The additional expression token values comes up and then it throws invalid token.

Comment: I have made changes to my original post to show how each screen looks like.

Comment: from the snips I see, you have headers as context-type, it should be Content-Type

Comment: And during import schema, just pass the token value, don't add `Bearer` as you are already using Concat() to form it

Comment: When I run for a single page without pagination it has no problem, but when I set it to pagination, it says invalid token.

Comment: Changed the context-type spell and also removed the Bearer from Import schema, but still the same, invalid token. This is the exact Authorization key @concat('Bearer ', activity('Token').output.access_token) and AbsoluteUrl $['@odata.nextLink']

Comment: `access_token` is an example and you should provide the exact `Property` refering the access token in the output result from web activity. Can you share a snip of the complete pipeline setup and web activity output you see

Comment: For absolute URL can you try $odata.nextLink

Comment: can you share output you find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xotIU.png) and what exactly are you trying to achieve, for better understanding to suggest

Comment: I see in your snip, you have set Authentication to `None` in web activity

Comment: I have added the outputs for both the activities and also the pipeline. I am using post method for the token url, in that I have provided the credentials in the body and set authentication to none.

Comment: oki this seems to be different. From the web activity output snip, we can see no property named `access_token` ! you are just getting the `refresh_token`. You sohuld actually use refresh token to get and access token. Are you refering any documentation

Comment: I don't have such a server to exactly repro and show to you

Comment: In rush I missed the top section. There is access token and other details present. I have updated a new snip with just the access token.

Comment: You mentioned you have provided credentials in the body of the POST, what credentials are these. This 401error may occur, if you try to use a delegated access token granted to a personal Microsoft account, to access an API that only supports work or school accounts (organizational accounts).

Comment: The link is https://-------/oauth2/v1/token and in the body is the request grant-type, clientid, usrnm and pw. I am using the link to get the token first. The oauth2/v1 is not present in the base url.

Comment: If am not wrong you are trying this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token

Comment: Yes, I am using the same thing with additional parameters grant type, clientid, username and password.

Comment: found this Note: Calling Microsoft Graph from a standalone web API is not currently supported by the Microsoft identity platform endpoint. For this scenario, you need to use the Azure AD endpoint.

Comment: I am not calling microsoft graph api though, it is a rest api for which I am using token link to get the token. Had to change the base url to anonymous since we are looking for authentication type as Oauth2 which is not present in Azure we have OAuth2Client and include the access token as header in copy function.

Comment: oki so you have the relative url configured in rest linked service ? try to setup like explained [here](https://lytix.be/connecting-and-using-ms-graph-in-azure-data-factory/#:~:text=document%20for%20later.-,Azure%20Data%20Factory,-Once%20the%20previous)

Comment: For the first method, it says GetAppRegSecrets with url as rest api, I am thinking on should I include the token url or base url? Or just the concat method for web url for token instead of writing in the body?

Comment: Okay, I may have got myself confused, in the rest dataset I have used dynamic query @dataset.tables, should I change that to relativeurl?

Comment: try relative URL